# Ideas to re-write looping regression with 'for' loops

Tags: r, regression

I'm having a brain freeze, and hoping one of you can point me in the right direction. My end goal is the output of various regression coefficients (mainly interested in price elasticity), which I achieved via simple multiple regression, using the "by" function.

I am using the "by" function to loop through the regression formula for each iteration of the "State.UPC" variable. Since my data is quite large (~1MM rows), I had to subset my data into groups of 3-4 states (see mystates1...mystates10). I am then performing the regression on those subsets, each time changing my data source in the "datastep3" data frame. And this is where I need your help:

What is the best way to efficiently re-write this with a combination of my existing "by" regression function, and the "for" loops, so I can bypass the step of constantly changing the data frame name in "datastep3" and the "write.csv" steps. Essentially R looping through each "mystates" data subset and doing the regression by the "State.UPC" attributes?

I have tried several combinations with no success. Pardon the amateurish question...still learning R. Here is my code:

```
data <-read.csv("PriceData.csv")
datastep1 <-subset(data, subset=c(X..Vol>0, Unit.Vol>0))
datastep2 <- transform(datastep1, State.UPC = paste(State,UPC, sep="."))

mystates1 <- c("AL","AR","AZ")
mystates2 <- c("CA","CO","FL")
mystates3 <- c("GA","IA","IL")
mystates4 <- c("IN","KS","KY")
mystates5 <- c("LA","MI","MN")
mystates6 <- c("MO","MS","NC")
mystates7 <- c("NJ","NM","NV")
mystates8 <- c("NY","OH","OK")
mystates9 <- c("SC","TN","TX")
mystates10 <- c("UT","VA","WI","WV")


datastep3 <-subset(datastep2, subset=State %in% mystates10)
datastep4 <-na.omit(datastep3)


PEbyItem <- by(datastep4, datastep4$State.UPC, function(df) 
  lm(log(Unit.Vol)~log(Price) + Distribution+Independence.Day+Labor.Day+Memorial.Day+Thanksgiving+Christmas+New.Years+
   Year+Month, data=df))

x <- do.call("rbind",lapply(PEbyItem, coef))
y <-data.frame(x)


write.csv(x, file="mystates10.csv", row.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to test this because you do not provide any data, but theoretically you could just combine the various `mystatesN` into a list and then run `lapply(...)` on that.

```
## Not tested...
get.PEbyItem <- function(i) {
  datastep3 <-subset(datastep2, subset=State %in% mystates[[i]])
  datastep4 <-na.omit(datastep3)
  PEbyItem  <- by(datastep4, datastep4$State.UPC, function(df) 
    lm(log(Unit.Vol)~log(Price) + Distribution+Independence.Day+Labor.Day+
       Memorial.Day+Thanksgiving+Christmas+New.Years+Year+Month, 
       data=df))
  x <- do.call("rbind",lapply(PEbyItem, coef))
  y <-data.frame(x)
  write.csv(x, file=paste(names(mystates[i]),"csv",sep="."), row.names=TRUE)
}

mystates <- list(ms1=mystates1, ms2=mystates2, ..., ms10=mystates10)
lapply(1:length(mystates),get.PEbyItem)
```

There are lots of other things that could be improved but without the dataset it's pointless to try.

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks a lot. Will study the code to fully understand and use the logic in the future.

Comment: akakas - the \*apply functions (apply, lapply, sapply, tapply etc) are among the central workhorses of 'idiomatic' R. You get much more back for the effort of learning them. They're not *necessarily* faster (in some cases, perhaps even a little slower than a well-written loop), but they make for more compact and understandable/maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b . I will definitely work to get those functions more embedded.